# UIPageViewController caching issue when waiting for new data

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I am using `UIPageViewController` to show images. If no data for a given image is received from the server I want the user to be able to slide, but to not be able to go to the next view controller / unloaded image. So I return nil in the datasource method `pageViewController(_:viewControllerAfter:)`. The code is something like:

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let nextImageIndex = currentImageIndex + 1

    if nextImageIndex >= currentImagesCount && currentImagesCount < totalImagesCount {
        return nil
    }

    return getNewController(forIndex: nextImageIndex)
}
```

The problem is that the `UIPageViewController` has some caching. So if the user just continues to slide, they won’t ever see the newly received image. 
Is there a good way to handle this?

What I tried so far:

```
func onNewImage() {
    pageViewController.dataSource = nil
    pageViewController.dataSource = pageViewController
}
```

This kind of solves it in a sense that the user will be able to eventually slide to the next page, but leads to many more bugs.

Is there another approach to this? I have tried to preload some images in advance, but on slower internet connection this case still exists.

Comment: I may not fully understand your question, but in general, when presenting images you're downloading from the net: **almost everyone uses some sort of caching library**. Example, we always uise Nuke ( github.com/kean/Nuke ) but there are a couple to choose from. Again don't totally follow the question but maybe that's the approach!  Good luck!

Comment: @Fattie this is about the caching that UIPageViewController makes of the controllers (pages) it shows, but thank you for your reply!

Comment: thank you!  Sorry I misunderstood.  I really did not know that about UIPVC caching!